# Boomeranged to old employer 2 years ago. Want to look for new job

Tags: resume, management

I worked for a company for 10 years in a management role. I left for what was a seemingly good opportunity.  However when I got to the new job the position had changed between the time I interviewed and the time I started (for example, I was supposed to have a team of 4 resources, but I was told by the director on day 1 that I would not have a team for the foreseeable future).  My old employer offered me the chance to return 6 months after I left which I accepted.

Fast forward to today (18 months later) and the company is now struggling and turnover is way up. Morale is way down and I want to look for a new job, but I am not sure how to handle the short stint on my resume.

Should I leave it off my resume or should I include it in the chronology?

Comment: I believe this is substantially a dupe of past's "what to say about short stay" questions....

Comment: I suspect if you do this again you're going to seriously annoy your current employer, so you'd also need to be prepared for a very poor reference from your current job. Their lesson is likely to be "if someone leaves, that's it". Which takes burning your bridges to a new level, in that you're also hurting anyone else who wants to return to your current company.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue for you is how you structure the rest of the resume.

If you list all the other jobs except this one, they may notice the gap. If they do they will ask you about it.

If the detour was all in one calendar year you may think that instead of always listing the month and year you will just list the year for all the jobs. This could lead to a problem:

- First time Feb 2003 to May 2013
- Detour Job May 2013 to December 2013
- Second time December 2013 to August 2015 (present)

You try and collapse them to:

- One company 2003 to 2015 (present)

The issue will be if they call your current employer and they mention the gap. You didn't just skip the company you fudged the dates to hide the employer

I would just list it. Tell them what you accomplished. But if you really don't think that there is enough positives to write about don't list it but don't hide it. Be prepared to be asked about it. Know how you will respond. Don't be defensive about it. Tell them the job wasn't what you were promised, you made the best of it, and decided to return to your former employer when that opportunity presented itself.

They will be concerned you could do that gain. But reassure them that due to the changes in the current company you have no intention of going back.